# CSS Grid with vertical and horizontal overflow

Tags: css

I'm trying to use display: grid to make a layout with a variable amount of columns, with horizontal and vertical overflow and the first column being a specific width.

Each of the columns, besides the first, should be the same width.
For example,

```
grid-template-columns: 49px repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
```

makes the first column the correct width, and columns after 300px - **until reaching the overflowing columns**, which ignore the 300px.

The vertical scroll is achieved with overflow-y and a specified height.

```
overflow-y: scroll;
height: 70vh;
```

And the horizontal css so far is:

```
grid-template-columns: 49px repeat(auto-fit, 300px);
grid-auto-flow: column;
overflow-x: scroll;
width: 100%;
```

**Stack snippet:**

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 49px repeat(auto-fit, 300px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="first-item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Paint attempt to visualise the goal:
[image: Grid Paint Example]

Comment: Do you need to use grid? Because it seems a good job for flex. 
Like: flex: 1 0 300px

Comment: @yannickvdthoren I probably could, but I've been using grid everywhere else. Suddenly switching to Flex for this one thing didn't feel right :P Thanks for the alternative solution though!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this by omitting `grid-template-columns` and defining the `width` separately:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 70vh;
}

.first-item {
  width: 49px;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="first-item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!! I found a jank work-around using grid-template-columns in-between your answer:
grid-template-columns: 49px repeat(999999, minmax(300px, whateverMaxIWant));
But not very elegant to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grid-auto-columns` and you don't need to specify any CSS on the child items

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 49px; /* 1st column */
  grid-auto-columns: 300px; /* all the others */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 70vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="first-item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is indeed the better solution...